# Missing Windows Desktop Extension SDK for UWP

Tags: c#, wpf, uwp, desktop-bridge

I try to repeat this [manual](https://stefanwick.com/2018/04/06/uwp-with-desktop-extension-part-1/).
My project is blank WPF + blank UWP app.

- Target ver. Windows 10 (1903), 10.0 Build 18362
- Min ver. Windows 10 (1903), 10.0; Build 17763

I have installed SDK Windows 10 (10.0.18362.0) [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ktpJ9.png)

I don't have references **Windows Desktop Extension SDK for UWP**. [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4MqnL.png)

What is wrong? How to add Windows Desktop Extension SDK for UWP to my project?

I tried install all version SDK from 16299 to 18362, reinstalled and repaired the vs studio. Manual installed Windows 10 SDK from microsoft it also did not help. I found [information](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-iotcore-samples/issues/200) that Windows Desktop Extension SDK for UWP was merged to main UWP packet.

But when i try run the project without Windows Desktop Extension SDK i get error

**Error CS0103  The name 'FullTrustProcessLauncher' does not exist in the current context**.

```
        if (ApiInformation.IsApiContractPresent("Windows.ApplicationModel.FullTrustAppContract", 1, 0))
        {
            await FullTrustProcessLauncher.LaunchFullTrustProcessForCurrentAppAsync();
        }
```

I have the same error when i try to run github example from manul without Windows Desktop Extension SDK

Comment: What version of VS are you running?

When I try the same as you describe, I see this:
https://stefanwick.files.wordpress.com/2020/01/capture.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution found.

For random reason your Windows SDK can be installed to wrong directory. For me it is
`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Platform SDK`. Right path is `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10`
I just made symbol link

```
mklink /j “C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10” “C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Platform SDK”
```